# Speed up Pandas DateTime variable

Tags: performance, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I have a number of quite large cvs files (1,000,000 rows each) which contain a DateTime column. I am using Pandas pivot tables to summarise them. Part of what this involves is splitting out this DateTime variable into hours and minutes. I am using the following code, which is working fine, but it is taking quite a lot of time (around 4-5 minutes).

My question is: Is this just because the files are so large/my laptop to slow, or is there a more efficient code that allows me to split out hours and minutes from a DateTime variable?

Thanks

```
df['hours'], df['minutes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']).hour, pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']).minute
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your input CSV file (5-7 rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dtypes` of column `Datetime` is not `datetime`, first convert it [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then use [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and [`dt.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html):

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['hours'], df['minutes'] = df['DateTime'].dt.hour, df['DateTime'].dt.minute
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['2014-06-17 11:09:20', '2014-06-18 10:02:10']})
print (df)
              DateTime
0  2014-06-17 11:09:20
1  2014-06-18 10:02:10

print (df.dtypes)
DateTime    object
dtype: object

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['hours'], df['minutes'] = df['DateTime'].dt.hour, df['DateTime'].dt.minute
print (df)
             DateTime  hours  minutes
0 2014-06-17 11:09:20     11        9
1 2014-06-18 10:02:10     10        2
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! followed your first approach, down to 6-7 seconds now per batch

Comment: showing list comprehensions for a pandas native op (except for a perf comparison) just confuses people